# Hover td escapes background-color change from hover tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a general class that I use for table rows which changes the `background-color` of it's td 's when they are hovered. I'm using it all over my application.

```
.enty-table {
    &:hover > td {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

 <table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Min Length</th>
             <th>Max Length</th>
             <th>Min Value</th>
             <th>Max Value</th>
             <th>Regular Expr</th>
             <th>Default Value</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr class="enty-table">
             <!-- I want the hover on the folowing td to escape the hover effect added with enty-table class on tr -->
             <td class="columnCategory">Business Fields</td>
             <td><strong>new column1</strong></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="enty-table">
             <td><strong>new column2</strong></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
             <td><span></span></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now, I have a special table (2 dimensional) where in the first column I have td 's with rowspan.

[image: My table]

Eventually I want to get rid of background-color change when I hover the *rowspan td*:

[image: unwanted effect]

When I hover on the `Business Fields` *td* the hover effect is applied for the `new column1` row, but when I hover on the second row it is not applied on the *td* with *rowspan*. I'm want to fix that by removing the hover action from the first *td*.

How can I escape the hover effect on the *rowspan td*, but keep it for the table rows (the individual subrows - `new column1` , `new column2`)?

Can it only be done from CSS?

Comment: Show us your html.. Or even better provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class to ignore the `<td>` has `rowspan` attribute, then use **[CSS general sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)** to reset the background color of table cells, as follows:

```css
.enty-table {
  &:hover > td:not([rowspan]) {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  & > td[rowspan]:hover ~ td {
    background-color: #fff; /* Reset the background of next cells */
  }
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/IWUtAcAX/1/edit)**.

### Update

If using CSS `:not()` is not an option, you could reset the `background-color` of the first cell as follows:

```css
.enty-table {
  &:hover > td {
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* Reset the background color of td[rowspan] */
    &[rowspan] {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  }

  & > td[rowspan]:hover ~ td {
    background-color: #fff; /* Reset the background */
  }
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/IWUtAcAX/2/edit)**.

---

> Basically what I need is when I hover that td there will be nothing applied on the tr

Actually, you're hovering the `tr` itself, not only that `td` (refers to `td[rowspan]`)

> Is it possible to go higher in the tree structure from CSS

CSS is cascading, there's no backward and/or parent selector ([yet](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/)).

As a Pure CSS way, you could use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the `td[rowspan]` to prevent from triggering the mouse event on that element.

**[Working Demo #3](http://jsbin.com/IWUtAcAX/4/edit)**.

Otherwise, you need to use JavaScript to change all table-cells on hovering each one excluding `td[rowspan]`.

For instance:

```javascript
$('.enty-table').children('td:not(td[rowspan])').hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings(':not(td[rowspan])').addBack().addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().children('td').removeClass('hover');
});
```

**[Working Demo #4](http://jsbin.com/IWUtAcAX/6/edit)**.

Comment: That almost worked for me! Your example rewrites the propriety for the neighbor td's. In my case I want to avoid it. Basically what I need is when I hover that td there will be nothing applied on the tr. I'm not a CSS dev so I don't know: Is it possible to go higher in the tree structure from CSS or the solution would be JavaScript?

Comment: @razvan I've just updated the answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes. Good explanation for all the methods! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could do:

```
.enty-table {
    & td:hover {
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }
}
.enty-table {
    & tr:hover {
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could remove `& ` at the first of selectors. Using a space character after the ampersand makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it. Use class tree and change style using selected object. It will work fine for all "TD"s using proper tree pattern.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".enty-table tr td").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
  });
  $(".enty-table tr td").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","lightgray");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vDD5p/

Comment: I don't want to apply hover on individual td's. I want hover on a td element to escape hover of parent parent tr. The rest of the tr should have the normal hover effect.